# Getting started with delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, delayed-job

I am using ROR and mongodb. The application is deployed on Heroku. I want to run few delayed jobs on amazon ec2. For that I came across this commands

```
git pull on your repo.
chmod 600 xyz.pem
ssh -i xyz.pem ubuntu@ec2-234-33-37-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I have worked with heroku but not with ec2 , if anybody can point me any good resources or explain for getting started with setup of dealyed_job in amazon ec2.

Things I know:
1) How to implement delayed jobs in the code.

Things that I don't know and have doubts:
1) How to setup the new machine on amazon ec2 to have the rails repo?
2)How to run delayed_jobs by connecting to app mongo database which is in heroku.?

Comment: you should research the things you don't know. Check the docs, try some things out, come back with specific problems.

Comment: sorry drew, but I actually figured it out a long back. I just used delay gem on heroku and started hohup rake job on amazon ec2.

Answer (score 1):

### 1) How to setup the new machine to have the rails repo?

You can automatically configure a new  machine in a number of ways. Some popular ways to do this are Puppet/Chef/SaltStack.

For a very simple setup, you might just want to run a script. AWS allows you to supply a script (via UserData) when launching a machine. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Here is an example of a UserData script you might supply to AWS:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e -x

apt-get --yes --quiet update
apt-get --yes --quiet install git

git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git /destination/folder
```

### 2) How to run delayed_jobs by connecting to app mongo database?

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

**Delayed Jobs**

Call .delay.method(params) on any object and it will be processed in the background.

```
# without delayed_job 
@user.activate!(@device)

# with delayed_job 
@user.delay.activate!(@device)
```

**Mongo**

If you plan to use delayed_job with Mongoid, add delayed_job_mongoid to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'
```

Edit: Further Reading http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2013/06/10/backgrounding-tasks-in-heroku-with-delayed-job/ and https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid

Comment: I am using two server heroku and amazon ec2. How can i connect mongo database to amazon web server which is on heroku.

Comment: You need to be more clear when asking your question above. Outline your question along with what you have tried so far.